How to hang over-the-sink drying rack/shelving from the inside wall behind overhead cabinet? (Rental-friendly suggestions needed)
As a former New Yorker who's never earned much, I thought I knew tiny kitchens. My current apartment, located far away in Texas (admittedly, downtown & in a big city), proved me wrong. While everything else about the place is perfect, the kitchen is a hellscape with none of the wiggle room required to make "tips to maximize space in a small kitchen" workable...and either tiled walls or 1930s-era custom doors/cabinetry that I can't drill into blocking me from installing anything useful.
After much study and experimentation, I've determined that this 36" wide x 12" deep x 34" high space above my sink represents the one and only spot that could accommodate a reasonable enough amount of additional storage: (Sorry for mess/bad photo.)

It would change my life if I could install a dish rack and at least one shelf there. Since I can't take a drill to the tile/cabinets surrounding the area, I've been searching for alternative options. I tried THIS for a while, but it was super rickety, and moving it to clean the crud out from under the feet was both a pain and a contributor to its instability.
How would you all approach mounting something in this case?
Here's what I've been considering: I discovered that the crevices between the upper cabinets (the ones hung over the sink) and the back and side walls underneath it (where I need shelving/storage) are sufficient to thread something about .5 to 1 mm thick through them. I wonder about talking some pipe strapping (like THIS), attaching it to the back of the inside of the cabinet, threading it through the crevice, mounting pegboard or a piece of plywood to the straps hanging underneath the cabinet, and then mounting racks/shelves to the pegboard/plywood. Is this bananas? (I feel like I've lost all sense of what's reasonable at this point, so please be direct ;))
I've also looked at various overhead-mounted shelving options, but I'm not sure hanging something like this from a wall-mounted cabinet would be a good idea. (The aesthetics of out-of-the-box overhead shelving also really clash with those of the kitchen and would bug me, I think.)
Any other suggestions, warnings re what NOT to do, off-the-wall experiments to consider? I'd be very grateful for any/all of them. TIA for reading this :)


Ask the landlord about mounting shelves. 2) Consider something that stands on legs rather than hanging on the wall?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Can you get us some photos of the cabinet bottoms at the edges—looking outward from the middle of the cabinet?  Could you mount a dish rack using tension rods?

@Huesmann   Would you really trust tension rods to hold a dish rack full of dishes.

Thanks for the comments and questions, y'all! @keshlam, I'll ask. This is an eccentric place run by a property manager w/ dementia. After 2 yrs here, I predict that the (very kind) manager will offer to visit/send the folks he hires for repairs/maintenance to help me w/ the issue, and then 1 of 2 things will happen: Either no one will ever arrive or someone will stop by, share a few friendly but vague thoughts about what could be done and then leave, never to be seen again, lol. As for something on legs, had a rough time w/ this before but maybe worth investing in something more heavy duty?

@Huesmann, will do!

As for tension rods, I think @crip659 are on the same page about the risk of failure. Perhaps, the rods could be bolstered by those side supports they sell on Amazon, but I'd need to find a way to affix the supports to the cabinetry/tile securely. Wondering if there's a glue that would work and could be removed later?

@crip659 how about fastening the rack to the walls with something like these? https://www.tesa.com/en/consumer/mounting-hanging-sms/adhesive-hooks/powerstrip-hooks They claim up to 12kg for some of their products, e.g. double powerbutton, and should work with the tile and wood substrates.  Could simply wire tie or zip tie the rack to the pegs on the walls.

@Huesmann   Claim up to,  is only for perfect conditions.   A full dish rack might need all that and a bit more.   Anything breakable and/or expensive I want it sitting on a surface, on decent legs or screwed into studs.  Adhesives/springs can weaken/slip over time.  Have a couple of adhesive hooks.  Use for hanging up light house coats.  One has lasted for years, the other one felled off of the door.

@crip659 Well, barring new photos that show possible mounting points inside the cabinet rim, that's all I got.  Maybe supporting 3 corners would be sufficient—you could basically put a support strut down to the counter, below the left front, left rear, and right rear of the rack.  Then jam another strut at the same points between the rack and the cabinet—basically box the rack in between counter and cabinet.  (And use one of the removable wall hangers on the right front, and another on the left wall to keep the rack hoizontally positioned.)
